# Can we use Popupmenu in FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am developing a mobile app in FMX where i need Popupmenu but it is showing disable in Tool Palette i cant use it but in VCL its enabled in Tool Palette and can use it. I just want to know if Firemonkey supports Popupmenu or my installation is having problems or we have to use other tools instead of Popupmenu in FMX? or what else can I do?

and actually i opened one VCL project and copied popupmenu from there to FMX and wrote code on one button and that code is

```
procedure TFRM_Party.BTN_Party_OptionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopupMenu1.Popup(10,10);
  PopupMenu1.Parent := Self;
end;
```

this code is not showing any error and also not performing also.
what to do? anybody having idea?

[image]

Comment: I removed some tags, as they are not significant for your question. You should however add the tag for your Delphi version, or indicate it in the text of your question.

Comment: Mixing code from `Vcl` to `Fmx` or vv. will most likely fail, even though it might be possible in some special cases. Do not rely on such solutions.  A properly begun `FMX` project offers and accepts the `TPopupMenu` component just fine. If you describe in details what steps you take to create a new project and attempt to use the menu component, somebody can evaluate what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "Yes", you ought to be able to use the FMX version of `TPopupMenu` in a project created from `File | New |Multi-Device Application` in the IDE.  If you can't find the FMX `TPopupMenu` on the Component Palette, something must be wrong with your Delphi install.  I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say that it's "disabled" - components are usually either on the Component Palette or not, I don't recall seeing one looking disabled there.

You don't say in your question which version of Delphi you are using, but if it has FireMonkey at all, AFAIK it definitely ought to have the FMX version of `TPopupMenu`.

In Delphi 10.2 Seattle, for example, the FMX `TPopupMenu` appears on the "Standard" tab of the component palette, and is contained in the source unit `FMX.Menus` along with `TMenuBar` and `TMainMenu`, amongst others.

If you go to `Component | Install packages` in the IDE, the pop-up should show `Embarcadero FMX Standard Components` in the list, which is the file `dclfmxstd250.bpl` in the `bin` folder of your Delphi install. If that package isn't listed, that explains why you can't find the FMX `TPopupMenu`, but if that's the case for you, your Delphi ought to be lacking a lot more FMC components besides `TPopupMenu`.  However, it should be easily solved by installing the `.bpl` file (or equivalent in your Delphi version).  If the package *is* there, clicking the `Components` button to the bottom right of the pop-up should bring up the entire list of FXM standard components (which in my case *does* include `TPopupMenu`).

If your Delphi *does* include the `Embarcadero FMX Standard Components` but is still lacking `TPopupMenu`, you might try creating a new Package, adding `FMX.Menus.pas` to it and compiling and installing it in the IDE.

BTW, although it is *possible* to set up a combined FMX + VCL project (Google for how), just because you might be able to put a VCL `TPopupMenu` on an FMX Form doesn't mean that it's going to work.

Comment: FYI, Seattle is 10.0. Tokyo is 10.2.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Thanks.  The installer from my ESD file announces itself as "Rad Studio 10 Seattle"  whereas Help | About says "Embarcadero® Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.31059.3231" but nothing about Tokyo.  I wish they'd drop the geographical nonsense, it achieves nothing but confusion, imo.  Will ther be a "Wuhan" version, I wonder?

Comment: @MartynA Thanks. i am using Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753.I have uploaded image i think it will help u to get clear.I also checked  component | Install packages. its available over there.

Answer (score 0):

Components are Grayed  if you can't use its on current OS(your current choice in top combobox)